# Different of columns based on date column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has date ( Mon-YY) and interest columns. I have to derive additional columns as interest_year , interest_month, interest_quarter.

I have tried using the lag function and i am able to get these columns but this only works if all the months are in order and no month is missing.

Data:

```
INTEREST_DATE | INTEREST_RATE
--------------|--------------
Dec-21        | 7.5
Jan-22        | 7.6
Feb-22        | 7.6
Mar-22        | 7.8
Apr-22        | 7.9
May-22        | 8.2
Jun-22        | 8.5
July-22       | 8.5
Aug-22        | 8.6
Sep-22        | 8.7
Oct-22        | 8.9
Nov-22        | 9.1
Dec-22        | 9.3
Jan-23        | 9.5
```

```
select
  interest_date,
  interest_rate,
  case
    when LAG(interest_rate,12) over (order by to_date(interest_date,'Mon-YY')) is null
    then 0
    else interest_rate - LAG(interest_rate,12) over (order by to_date(interest_date,'Mon-YY')) 
  end as interest_year
from Interest
```

Output:

```
INTEREST_DATE | INTEREST_RATE | INTEREST_YEAR
--------------|---------------|--------------
Dec-21        | 7.5           | 0
Jan-22        | 7.6           | 0
Feb-22        | 7.6           | 0
Mar-22        | 7.8           | 0
Apr-22        | 7.9           | 0
May-22        | 8.2           | 0
Jun-22        | 8.5           | 0
July-22       | 8.5           | 0
Aug-22        | 8.6           | 0
Sep-22        | 8.7           | 0
Oct-22        | 8.9           | 0
Nov-22        | 9.1           | 0
Dec-22        | 9.3           | 1.8
Jan-23        | 9.5           | 1.9
```

Interest_year for dec-22 is (dec-22 - dec-21) and this works

if there is a missing month in between or if this is not in order.. lag function will not work.

is there any other way to achieve this?

https://dbfiddle.uk/3CPTsP2n

Comment: `order by to_date(some_date,'Mon-YY')` doesn't handle date order properly and calculation is messed up as a consequence. Please describe how do you want to calculate your new columns (using general words, not necessarily in SQL) and add more sample data to demonstrate the issue you face (and test this case using provided answers) and desired output for those edge cases.

Comment: What is the relationship between interest year and the column interest_date ? What values are you expecting and why ? When I read your question I assumed that interest_year, month and qtr for Dec-21 would be 21, 12 and 1 but you show an analytical function in your own query.

Comment: @astentx What i am getting is the MCLR rates of a bank. I have to come up with the columns for 1Y MCLR, 3M MCLR, 6M MCLR, 1M MCLR. If a customer has taken a loan with 1Y MCLR rate in DEC'22.. Then in Dec'23 his interest rate will be changed to MCLR rate on Dec'23 + (Dec'23- Dec'22) . I want to have these interest rates derived before in a different table  and want to add the 1Y MCLR rates to the interest based on the month he has taken the loan.

Comment: @KoenLostrie ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function with a `RANGE` window to get the latest value from at least 12 months ago:

```sql
SELECT interest_date,
       interest_rate,
       COALESCE(
         interest_rate
         - LAST_VALUE(interest_rate) IGNORE NULLS OVER (
             ORDER BY  TO_DATE(interest_date, 'Mon-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
           ),
         0
       ) AS interest_year
FROM   Interest
```

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` self-join and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to get the most recent preceding interest rate:

```sql
SELECT i.interest_date,
       i.interest_rate,
       COALESCE(i.interest_rate - ly.interest_rate, 0) AS interest_year
FROM   Interest i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT ly.interest_rate
         FROM   interest ly
         WHERE  TO_DATE(ly.interest_date, 'Mon-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
                <= ADD_MONTHS(
                     TO_DATE(i.interest_date, 'Mon-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
                     -12
                   )
         ORDER BY
                TO_DATE(ly.interest_date, 'Mon-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) ly
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| INTEREST_DATE | INTEREST_RATE | INTEREST_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec-21 | 7.5 | 0 |
| Jan-22 | 7.6 | 0 |
| Feb-22 | 7.6 | 0 |
| Mar-22 | 7.8 | 0 |
| Apr-22 | 7.9 | 0 |
| May-22 | 8.2 | 0 |
| Jun-22 | 8.5 | 0 |
| July-22 | 8.5 | 0 |
| Aug-22 | 8.6 | 0 |
| Sep-22 | 8.7 | 0 |
| Oct-22 | 8.9 | 0 |
| Nov-22 | 9.1 | 0 |
| Dec-22 | 9.3 | 1.8 |
| Jan-23 | 9.5 | 1.9 |

*Note: you should probably store your `interest_date` column as a `DATE` data type (and not as a string) then you will not need to continually convert it to a `DATE` to be able to order it. You could also add a constraint `CHECK( interest_date = TRUNC(interest_date, 'MM') )` to ensure that the date is always midnight of the first day of the month.*

---

If you want the value from exactly 12 months ago (and not the latest value from at least 12 months ago) then, for the `LAST_VALUE` solution, change the `RANGE` window to:

```sql
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
          AND INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
```

and, for the `LATERAL` self-join solution, change `<=` to `=`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/de8LoyaB)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the whole example - putting your in-data into a WITH clause's CTE to select from:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                     
indata(interest_date,interest_rate) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2021-12-01',7.5  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-01-01',7.6  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-01',7.6  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-03-01',7.8  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-04-01',7.9  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-05-01',8.2  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-06-01',8.5  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-07-01',8.5  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-08-01',8.6  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-09-01',8.7  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-10-01',8.9  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-11-01',9.1  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-12-01',9.3  FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-01-01',9.5  FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  interest_date
, interest_rate
, LAST_VALUE(interest_rate) OVER(
    ORDER BY interest_date
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING 
              AND INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
  ) AS i1yb4
FROM indata;
```

| INTEREST_DATE | INTEREST_RATE | I1YB4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-DEC-21 | 7.5 | *null* |
| 01-JAN-22 | 7.6 | *null* |
| 01-FEB-22 | 7.6 | *null* |
| 01-MAR-22 | 7.8 | *null* |
| 01-APR-22 | 7.9 | *null* |
| 01-MAY-22 | 8.2 | *null* |
| 01-JUN-22 | 8.5 | *null* |
| 01-JUL-22 | 8.5 | *null* |
| 01-AUG-22 | 8.6 | *null* |
| 01-SEP-22 | 8.7 | *null* |
| 01-OCT-22 | 8.9 | *null* |
| 01-NOV-22 | 9.1 | *null* |
| 01-DEC-22 | 9.3 | 7.5 |
| 01-JAN-23 | 9.5 | 7.6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZfD78ngw)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SELF JOIN` and `KEEP` clause with aggregate function `MAX` as follows:

```
SELECT I.interest_date, I.INTEREST_RATE,
       COALESCE(I.interest_rate - MAX(Y.INTEREST_RATE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST 
         ORDER BY to_date(Y.interest_date,'Mon-YY') DESC), 0) AS INTEREST_YEAR
  FROM Interest I
LEFT JOIN Interest Y 
  ON to_date(Y.interest_date,'Mon-YY') <= ADD_MONTHS(to_date(I.interest_date,'Mon-YY'),-12)
GROUP BY I.interest_date, I.INTEREST_RATE
ORDER BY to_date(I.interest_date,'Mon-YY');
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QH4p_bCd)